# check a condition for all elements in a div individually

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with class `'container'` which has many div within it with class `'children'`. I want to do an operation on the `'children'` div when it scrolls into view.

I tried using this.

```
$('.container .children').each(function(){
    var element = this;
    if(functionToCheckVisibility($(element))){
        //my code
    }
});
```

But it doesn't makes a change.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"when it appears on the screen"* - Do you mean you want to detect when it scrolls into view, or detect when formerly hidden divs are made visible by other code, or check which ones are currently visible? (Or...?)

Comment: I want the event to happen when `'.children'` scrolls into view.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do ?
http://jsfiddle.net/n4pdx/

Comment: yes.. I want to do an animation when the child comes into viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `$el.is(':visible')`:

```
$('.container .children').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':visible')){
        // code
    }
});
```

If by "visible" you mean "currently visible on the screen", I would use [this library](https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery) for that. Otherwise, the code above should work fine.

Comment: I want to check whether it scrolled into view or not

Comment: Did you read the part of my answer that linked to a library that does that? It allows you to easily know if an element can be currently viewed in the page or not. Calculating that by yourself is a pretty complex thing, so you should use a third-party library for that.

Comment: Thank you David..I used the library... It worked ... I used `$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.container .children').each(function(){
        if ($(this).visible()){
            /my code
        }
    });
});`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use function [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

```
$('.container').children('children').each(function(){
    var element = this;
    if(functionToCheckVisibility($(element))){
        //my code
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it: https://jsfiddle.net/0d8poebr/1/

```
$('.container .children').each(function(idx, el){
   if ($(el).is(':visible') && isScrolledIntoView(el)) {
        $(el).html('I am visible')
    }
});

function isScrolledIntoView(elem)
{
    var containerTop = $('.container').offset().top;
    var containerBottom = containerTop + $('.container').height();

    var elemTop = $(elem).offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $(elem).height();

    return ((elemBottom <= containerBottom) && (elemTop >= containerTop));
}
```

Comment: It works.. But the code is run only once.. I want to do the operation for every children individually..